# Django Model Field Uniqueness Validation

Tags: python, django

I have a django user model that has fields **ID**, **PW** and **DeviceID**. The database I'm using is MySQL. In this model a user can have many different devices, so there can be many identical ID & PW (same user), with different DeviceIDs in the table. But if all the 3 fields are the same, then it is considered the same record and shouldn't be allowed.

I wonder in django how I can do such a combined uniqueness validation to prevent users to do identical submissions? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/).

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = ('id', 'password', 'device_id')
```

It makes every model have a unique set of those three (which is what you want).